# Prove: If $A(x^*)$ is a matrix non singular and continuous at $x^*$ then...

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

If $A(x^*)$ is a matrix non singular and continuous at $x^*$ then there's a neighborhood of $x^*$ such that if $\|x-x^*\|<\varepsilon \rightarrow \|A(x)\|\leq 2\|A(x^*)\|$

This problem came to me while studying Numerical Optimization but the book (Nocedal) just give it without further explanation and I didn't understand why this happens. Could someone help me with this problem or recommend me where to check for a proof?

Comment: This seems like a straightforward application of continuity (with $\delta = \|A(x^*)\|$) and the reverse triangle inequality. I might be wrong since it's not exactly clear what $A$, $x^*$ and $A(x^*)$ are supposed to be. You should spell this out.

Comment: My problem came taking $A(x)=\nabla^2f(x)$ while studying the method of steepest descent and $\{x_k\}\to x^*$. $A$ is a function such that $A: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$